# Refreshing a specific instance of a form from another form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, listbox

Ok, my google-fu may be weak, but I'm having an issue that seems it should be pretty easy to get past, but everything I try is not working. And I have a slightly special case that makes many examples not relevant to my application.

Here's what I'm trying to do: I have a listbox on form1 that is populated from a database. I have a button on form1 that opens form2 so the user can enter a date and time. That date and time, plus some additional info, is written to the database, and form2 closes.

What I'm wanting is to have the write or close event on form2 to cause a refresh of the info in the listbox in form1.

The one major consideration is that the user might have up to 20+ instances of form1 opened at any one time. So I want it to refresh ONLY the form1 that spawned it.

I have many buttons on form1 that correctly refresh the listbox with the following code:

```
Private Sub refreshTimeLine()

    TimeLineListBox.Items.Clear()

    Try
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim str As String
        str = "SELECT TLEventTime,TLEventNotes FROM Timeline WHERE EventID = '" & eventId & "'"
        Dim cmd5 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        dr = cmd5.ExecuteReader()
        While dr.Read()
            Dim eventTime = dr("TLEventTime").ToString
            Dim eventNotes = dr("TLEventNotes")
            Dim tl = "[" & eventTime & "] - " & eventNotes & ""
            TimeLineListBox.Items.Add(tl)
        End While
        myConnection.Close()
    Catch exError As SystemException
        MsgBox("An Error Occurred. " & exError.Message)
        myConnection.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

In short, I would like this proc to run when form2 closes, so the user will see the changes in the listbox. But ONLY on the right form1 (not that it would hurt to refresh all the form1's, but with the number of users I could have, and with the number of form1's they could have open, the DB hit would be a concern). Just to get this working I've tried making the proc Public, and calling it from form2. And even though VS 2010 thought this was all good, and seemed to be linking back correctly, it simply doesn't trigger the proc.

What say you, Great and Mighty stackoverflow?

Comment: If you can show `Form2` using `ShowDialog`, call `refreshTimeLine` method in the next line after `ShowDialog`. It will execute after closing `Form2`. If you can't/don't want to use `ShowDialog`, make the `refreshTimeLine` method public and then pass an instance of `Form1` to `Form2`. Then you can call the `refreshTimeLine` method of passed instance in `Form2` when you need (for example in `Closing` event). If `Closing` event is the only where you want to call the method, then you even don't need to pass an instance to `Form2`. Just subscribe for the event in `Form1`, before showing `Form2`.

Comment: I like the ShowDialog idea, I haven't used it before but it's sounding like it would do what I'm looking for. I was thinking how great it would be if once the form was closed it would keep processing steps in the original call. If I'm understanding you right, that's what ShowDialog will do. Awesome! Thanks! I'll post up how it goes when I try it out.

Comment: Yes, it seems [`ShowDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you are looking for. You're welcome.

Comment: It worked! The only think I lost was being able to contain it in my Mdi, but I'll live with it!

Comment: Good job - Yes ShowDialog blocks all other windows:)